# Stick BottomNavigation View to Bottom with or without Scrolling in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview, android-appbarlayout

I have a `BottomNavigationView` Bar on my App. This bar does not show on where it is placed until it's scrolled.

How can I change the Behavior so that the bar shows even without scrolling. That is I want a permanent Fixed position to the bottom, if user does not scroll id remains there, if they scroll it remains there still.

Here is my app_bar xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sckoolboy.app.AspirantOfflineActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/master_bottom_navigation"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/accent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottomNavigationBackground"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And below is how this bar appears on my main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.sckoolboy.app.AspirantOfflineActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    style="@style/parent.contentLayout">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewUser"
                    style="@style/viewParent.headerText"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="Aspirant Mode"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profileCircleImageView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:minHeight="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Welcome to \nSckoolboy"
                                android:textColor="@color/whiteBodyColor"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textSize="20sp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="20% Complete"
                                android:textColor="@color/whiteBodyColor"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:textSize="13sp"/>

                        </LinearLayout>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/hero"
                            android:elevation="44dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="Popular"
                    style="@style/viewParent.headerText"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    style="@style/viewParent"
                    android:text="See All"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/headerMoreTextSize"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <!--remove the below layout with recycler view, use card poplar courses as model for design-->
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/includeCallEnd0"
                    layout="@layout/offline_exam_etest"/>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/includeCallEnd0"
                    layout="@layout/sckoolboy_community"/>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/includeCallEnd0"
                    layout="@layout/sckoolboy_radio"/>


            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `BottomNavigationView` out of the `CoordinatorLayout`, and add both to another root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    tools:context="com.sckoolboy.app.AspirantOfflineActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
      
      
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/master_bottom_navigation"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/accent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottomNavigationBackground"/>
        
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```